# Codingame : A child's play

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, loops, conditional-statements

I have a problem with a puzzle named "[A child's play](https://www.codingame.com/training/easy/a-childs-play)" of [Codingame](https://www.codingame.com/home). **I code in typescript !**

The statement is :

> For several years now, in elementary schools, we have seen the emergence of a new educational model, playful programming. The students must program a small robot using assembly blocks. This allows them to get familiar with programming from an early age while exercising their logic and perception of space.

> You are a student at one such school. The purpose of the exercise is simple: your teacher has crafted a circuit for your robot, told you how many moves n the robot may make, and you must find out the final position of the robot at end of execution.

> To do this you need to know some principles of robot operation.
> – When the robot encounters an obstacle (represented by #) it turns right (on same operation) until there's no obstacle ahead anymore. Otherwise on an empty area (represented by .) it moves straight ahead.
> – The robot initially moves upwards.
> – The robot stops after n moves.
> – The top left corner represents the coordinates (0,0)
> – The robot's environment is represented as follows, where O is the robot's initial position:

> ...#........ 
> ...........# 
> ............ 
> ............ 
> ..#O........ 
> ..........#.

I'm block at the test 4, because my solution is not optimized.

It gives me in the console: ***The process timed out. This may mean that your solution is not optimized enough to handle some cases***.

I tried to change the loop for a "while" loop and change and change the "switch" condition, for an "if-else" condition.

Can you help me to find a better solution or a other way to do the tests?

```
var inputs: string[] = readline().split(' ');
const w: number = parseInt(inputs[0]);
const h: number = parseInt(inputs[1]);
const n: number = parseInt(readline());
let zone: string[][] = [];
let robot: robot = { x: 0, y: 0 };

interface robot {
    x: number,
    y: number
}
for (let i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    const line: string = readline();
    zone = [...zone, line.split('')]
}

zone.forEach((line, y) => {
    line.forEach((place, x) => {
        if (place === "O") {
            robot.x = x;
            robot.y = y;
        }
    })
})

function getLoc(robot: robot, zone: string[][], tours: number) {
    let direct: string = "T";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < tours) {
        if (direct === "T") {
            if (zone[robot.y - 1][robot.x] === '#') {
                robot.x++;
                direct = "R";
            } else {
                robot.y--;
            }
        } else if (direct === "R") {
            if (zone[robot.y][robot.x + 1] === '#') {
                robot.y++;
                direct = "B";
            } else {
                robot.x++;
            }
        } else if (direct === "B") {
            if (zone[robot.y + 1][robot.x] === '#') {
                robot.x--;
                direct = "L";
            } else {
                robot.y++;
            }
        } else if (direct === "L") {
            if (zone[robot.y][robot.x - 1] === '#') {
                robot.y--;
                direct = "T";
            } else {
                robot.x--;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return robot
}

console.time("getLoc")
let res: robot = getLoc(robot, zone, n);
console.timeEnd("getLoc")
console.log(`${res.x} ${res.y}`)
```

Comment: Your algorithm has time complexity that is linear depending on the number of moves. There is no way to perform 2^53 operations in a reasonable amount of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The robot will go into a loop.

You have to figure out how long the loop is, then how many times it goes through it, then complete the last partial loop.

I recommend keeping an object saying when it was last at a given position and orientation.  When you find that it repeats, you now know the length of the loop and can jump over the repetitive behavior.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your tips, it was helped me for the resolution of the problem ! I did change the structure of main code, I did add three functions, *getSteps()* to get remaining moves and detect if there is a loop, *moveRobot()* to move the robot and get all moves. *getLoc()* to get the final position with the resultat of *getSteps()*. I reach the 8nth test, but i'm blocked at the 9nth test. The answer is **"1 3"**, but I get **"2 4"** ! I don't know how to solve this problem without break the rest.

The map is :

```js
#####
#...#
#.#.#
#...#
##O##
```

The code is :

```
var inputs: string[] = readline().split(' ');
const w: number = parseInt(inputs[0]);
const h: number = parseInt(inputs[1]);
const n: number = parseInt(readline());
let zone: string[][] = [];
let robot: robot = { x: 0, y: 0 };
let startRobot: startRobot = { x: 0, y: 0, loops: 1, steps: 0 };

interface startRobot extends robot {
    loops: number,
    steps: number
}

interface robot {
    x: number,
    y: number
}

for (let i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    const line: string = readline();
    zone = [...zone, line.split('')]
    console.error(line)
}

zone.forEach((line, y) => {
    line.forEach((place, x) => {
        if (place === "O") {
            robot.x = x;
            robot.y = y;
            startRobot.x = x;
            startRobot.y = y;
        }
    })
})

function getSteps(robot: robot, zone: string[][], steps: number, start: startRobot) {
    let direct: string = "T";
    var i: number = 0;
    var s: number = 0;
    let quotient: number = 0;
    let newSteps: number = 0;

    while (i < steps) {
        let resfunction = moveRobot(direct, zone, robot);
        robot = resfunction.robot;
        direct = resfunction.direct;
        i++;
        start.steps++;
        if (robot.x === start.x && robot.y === start.y) {
            s++;
        }
        if (s === start.loops) {
            quotient = steps / start.steps;
            newSteps = steps - start.steps * (Math.floor(quotient) - 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return newSteps
}

function moveRobot(direct: string, zone: string[][], robot: robot) {
    if (direct === "T") {
        if (robot.y - 1 >= zone.length) {
            if (zone[robot.y][robot.x] === '#') {
                robot.x++;
                direct = "R";
            } else {
                robot.y--;
            }
        } else {
            if (zone[robot.y - 1][robot.x] === '#') {
                robot.x++;
                direct = "R";
            } else {
                robot.y--;
            }
        }
    } else if (direct === "R") {
        if (robot.x + 1 >= zone[0].length) {
            if (zone[robot.y][robot.x] === '#') {
                robot.y++;
                direct = "B";
            } else {
                robot.x++;
            }
        } else {
            if (zone[robot.y][robot.x + 1] === '#') {
                robot.y++;
                direct = "B";
            } else {
                robot.x++;
            }
        }
    } else if (direct === "B") {
        if (robot.y + 1 >= zone.length) {
            if (zone[robot.y][robot.x] === '#') {
                robot.x--;
                direct = "L";
            } else {
                robot.y++;
            }
        } else {
            if (zone[robot.y + 1][robot.x] === '#') {
                robot.x--;
                direct = "L";
            } else {
                robot.y++;
            }
        }
    } else if (direct === "L") {
        if (robot.x - 1 >= zone[0].length) {
            if (zone[robot.y][robot.x] === '#') {
                robot.y--;
                direct = "T";
            } else {
                robot.x--;
            }
        } else {
            if (zone[robot.y][robot.x - 1] === '#') {
                robot.y--;
                direct = "T";
            } else {
                robot.x--;
            }
        }
    }
    return { direct, robot }
}

function getLoc(robot: robot, zone: string[][], steps: number, start: startRobot) {
    let direct: string = "T";
    var i: number = 0;

    while (i < steps) {
        let resfunction = moveRobot(direct, zone, robot);
        robot = resfunction.robot;
        direct = resfunction.direct;
        i++;
    }
    return robot
}

// console.time("getLoc")
let newSteps: number = getSteps(robot, zone, n, startRobot);
let res: robot = getLoc(robot, zone, newSteps, startRobot);
// console.timeEnd("getLoc")
console.log(`${res.x} ${res.y}`)
```